# Correct pattern to save a model that works with different tables

Tags: design-patterns

I'm developing an application where I should save information for a model. Specifically I have an Answer model that store the value of an input for a question. However, some questions accepts multiple answers (checkboxes), so I have to have conditionals to process this array in a different way of a single input. I want to know if there is pattern (maybe Strategy pattern?) to store this data depends of the type of question in the same model (Answer model). 
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a strategy pattern.

You can design your classes in this way:

```
public interface Question {
    public String getName();
    public AnswerType getAnswerType();
}

public interface Answer {
    public void accept(Question question);
    public String getValue();
}

public enum AnswerType {
    Singe,
    Checkbox
}
```

Now you can have multiple instances of `Answer` that can accept a certain type of it.

```
public class MultipleValuedAnswer implements Answer {
    // Implementations.
}

public class SingleValuesAnswer implements Answer {
    // Implementations.
}
```

And you can delegate the task of accepting the answer to a different class.

```
public class AnswerAcceptor {
    public void acceptAnswers(Question question) {
        if (question.getAnswerType() == AnswerType.Single) {
            new SingleValuedAnswer().accept(question);
        } else {
            new MultipleValuedAnswer().accept(question);
        }
    }
}
```

There might be better ways to do it, I have suggested one possibility.

Comment: You can always accept and upvote answers to help other people fund the relevant content easily (and help me Earth day rep xD)